# Global bookmarks in Delphi editor

Tags: delphi, ide, editor, delphi-xe

Is there any way to have bookmarks which will remember not only line, but file also in Delphi IDE? May be there's an expert (plugin) which provide such functionality?

I can workaround this with either Breakpoints or TODOs, however, what I need is bookmarks, so that they will not interfere with debugging and will be less permanent than TODOs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CnPack](http://www.cnpack.org/) has a Bookmark Browser which is exactly what you're looking for

Comment: Thanks. However, it shows only opened files. Don't you know if there any expert which will show list of bookmarks in project/project group files, even if some are closed?
I would be 100% satisfied with "old good" [CodeRush](http://www.componentsource.com/products/coderush/index.html) bookmarks, however, CodeRush is dead since D7, or even D6...

Comment: Finally found 'workaround' - as this wizard also saves all the bookmarks, I can view all bookmarks for project group/project simply by opening all of the project/group units (Ctrl+F12)